# Obtener todos los enlaces de una div específica

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Tengo [un sitio](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en#landing_menu) y hay un cuadro de diálogo desde el que quiero obtener todos los enlaces a los que permite acceder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sabe que proviene de lo siguiente en el código fuente:

```
<div class="events_menu_tabs" data-id="main">
        <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="#event_type_1" data-type-id="1">Presidential</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#event_type_3" data-type-id="3">Parliamentary</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#event_type_4" data-type-id="4">Adjara SC</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#event_type_5" data-type-id="5">Local</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#event_type_2" data-type-id="2">Voters List</a></li>
        </ul>
            <div id="event_type_1">
                <ul class="menu_list">
                        <li>
                                <ul class="menu_item clear">
                                    <li class="official_data">
                              <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official" title="Official Data"><img alt="Menu_official" src="/assets/menu_official-12f92a8c3e721f6eec8f989691f70f7a.png" /></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="event_name">
                          <span title="The results of the October 27, 2013 Presidential election. The President of Georgia is elected for a five year term.">
                            <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official">2013 Presidential</a>
                          </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <ul class="menu_item clear">
                                    <li class="official_data">
                              <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official" title="Official Data"><img alt="Menu_official" src="/assets/menu_official-12f92a8c3e721f6eec8f989691f70f7a.png" /></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="event_name">
                          <span title="The results of the January 5, 2008 Presidential election. The President of Georgia is elected for a five year term. This election was a snap election.">
                            <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official">2008 Presidential</a>
                          </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="event_type_3">
                <ul class="menu_list">
                        <li>
                                <ul class="menu_item clear">
                                    <li class="official_data">
                              <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/50/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official" title="Official Data"><img alt="Menu_official" src="/assets/menu_official-12f92a8c3e721f6eec8f989691f70f7a.png" /></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="event_name">
                          <span title="The results of the October 30, 2016 ruoff election for 50 majoritarian districts of Parliament. Members of Parliament are elected for four year terms.">
                            <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/50/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official">2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff</a>
                          </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <ul class="menu_item clear">
                                    <li class="official_data">
                              <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/49/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official" title="Official Data"><img alt="Menu_official" src="/assets/menu_official-12f92a8c3e721f6eec8f989691f70f7a.png" /></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="event_name">
                          <span title="The results of the October 22, 2016 rerun election for 4 precincts in two majoritarian districts of Parliament. Members of Parliament are elected for four year terms.">
                            <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/49/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official">2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun</a>
                          </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <ul class="menu_item clear">
                                    <li class="official_data">
                              <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/46/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official" title="Official Data"><img alt="Menu_official" src="/assets/menu_official-12f92a8c3e721f6eec8f989691f70f7a.png" /></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="event_name">
                          <span title="The results of the October 8, 2016 election for majoritarian districts of Parliament. Members of Parliament are elected for four year terms.">
                            <a href="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/46/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official">2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian</a>
                          </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
    ...
```

Por lo momento hice :

```
import requests
import re

with requests.Session() as s:
    webpage = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en#landing_menu'
    main_page = s.get(webpage)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.text, 'html.parser')

    urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', soup)
    print(', '.join(urls))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estás usando BeautifulSoup de la forma correcta. Aparentemente te limitas a usar una expresión regular para sacar todos los href que haya en el texto de la página, pero para eso no necesitarías BeautifulSoup, directamente podrías buscar sobre la cadena `main_page.text`. El problema es que de hacerlo así, sacarás todos los href presentes en la página y no los que a tí te interesan (que son los que están dentro de ciertos `div`).

La forma correcta es usar BeautifulSoup, en lugar de expresiones regulares, para que sea él quien te busque en primer lugar los `div` que son de tu interés, y seguidamente todos los tags `a` que haya dentro, y finalmente todas las urls asociadas a cada uno de esos tags.

De modo que vamos por partes

### Encontrar los DIV

Observando el HTML de la página, vemos que los div que buscas tienen todos diferente `id`, aunque el valor de ese `id` es muy similar, ya que se llaman `"event_type_1"`, `"event_type_2"`, etc. BeautifulSoup puede extraerte todos los div de la página, o sólo los que tengan un id dado. También (como necesitamos ahora) todos los que tengan un id que encaje con una cierta expresión regular. Así:

```
divs = soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile(r"event_type_\d+"))
print(len(divs))   # Sale que ha encontrado 10
```

### Extraer todos los `<a>` dentro de esos div

Cada elemento de la lista `divs` que acabamos de obtener, no es una cadena, sino otro objeto BeautifulSoup, sobre el que se puede hacer de nuevo `find_all()`. En este caso sería simplemente `find_all("a")`, para obtener los tags con los hiperenlaces buscados.

Por ejemplo, todos los `<a>` del primer div serían:

```
enlaces = divs[0].find_all("a")
```

El resultado es una lista con cuatro elementos en este caso. Cada uno de esos elementos es un tag `<a>` que tiene su `href`. Podemos ver estos `href` así:

```
for e in enlaces:
   print(e.get("href"))
```

Pero vemos que aparecen enlaces duplicados:

```
https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official
https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official
https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official
https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official
```

Ello se debe a que, debido a como está diseñada la página, se puede acceder a esos datos haciendo clic sobre un icono, o sobre una frase (ej: "2013 presidential"). Tanto el icono como la frase llevan a la misma URL, pero son dos tags diferentes y por eso aparecen enlaces duplicados. Podríamos hilar más fino y quedarnos sólo con aquellos que tengan un texto sobre el que hacer click. `e.text` te devuelve el texto contenido entre el tag de apertura `<a>` y el de cierre `</a>`.

```
for e in enlaces:
   if e.text:
      print("{}: {}".format(e.text, e.get("href")))
```

Y ahora sale:

```
2013 Presidential: https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official
2008 Presidential: https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official
```

Es más, podemos ir creando un diccionario en el que las claves sean los textos, y los valores sean las URLs a las que llevan.

## Todo junto

En `divs` teníamos una lista de los divs. Para cada elemento de esa lista hacemos un `find_all("a")` para sacar todos los elementos de tipo `<a>`. Para cada elemento de este nuevo resultado miramos si el enlace tiene texto, y en ese caso añadimos una entrada a nuestro diccionario de resultados.

```
resultado = {}

divs = soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile(r"event_type_\d+"))
for div in divs:
   enlaces = div.find_all("a")
   for e in enlaces:
      if e.text:
        resultado[e.text] = e.get("href")
```

En `resultado` tendremos (muestro solo parte):

```
{'2006 Voters List': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/2/event/4/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
 '2007 Voters List': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/2/event/1/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
 '2008 Adjara Supreme Council - Majoritarian': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/4/event/14/shape/38814/shape_type/2?data_type=official',
 '2008 Adjara Supreme Council - Majoritarian Re-run': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/4/event/20/shape/38814/shape_type/2?data_type=official',
 '2008 Adjara Supreme Council - Party List': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/4/event/13/shape/38814/shape_type/2?data_type=official',
 '2008 Adjara Supreme Council - Party List Re-run': 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/4/event/19/shape/38814/shape_type/2?data_type=official',
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas yo alguna lo hice con la librería requests_html

Lo primero que harias seria instalarte la libreria con el siguiente comando:

```
   pip install requests_html
```

Tomando el ejemplo que diste yo lo haría así:

```py
from requests_html import HTML
# guardas en una variable el codigo html que ya tienes en la variable doc
doc = """<div class="events_menu_tabls" data-id="main"> ...</div>""""  
html = HTML(html=doc)
print(html.links)
```

El resultado seria lo siguiente

Enlaces encontrados :

```
{
  'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
  'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/49/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
  'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/38/shape/69898/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
  'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/46/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official',
  'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/3/event/50/shape/89486/shape_type/1?data_type=official'
  }
```